# Transactionally create something, if allowed

Tags: python, validation, django, authorization

I have been looking over this block of code for hours trying to simplify it. Would there be a better way to check all those conditions before creating a `transaction` object without using so many if-elses?

```
def create(self, validated_data):

    user = self.context['request'].user
    if user.role == 'super_admin':  # ref PR 25.1
        return Transaction.objects.create(**validated_data)
    elif user.role == 'user' or user.role == 'org_admin' or user.role == 'site_admin':  # ref PR 25.4
        if check_user_institution_exists(validated_data['user_institution'].id):
            if check_user_belongs_to_institution(validated_data['user_institution'].id, None, user.id) > 0:
                if check_upload_permission(validated_data['user_institution'].id):
                    return Transaction.objects.create(**validated_data)
                else:
                    raise serializers.ValidationError({'Error': 'You do not have upload permission for this '
                                                                'institution.'})
            else:
                raise serializers.ValidationError({'Error': 'You do not belong to this institution.'})
        else:
            raise serializers.ValidationError({'Error': 'This user institution does not exist.'})
    else:
        raise serializers.ValidationError({'Error': 'You are not assigned a role.'})
```

Comment: Are you possibly missing an `else` for the outer-most if, elif?

Comment: You're right, I have edited my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You don't need to use `elif` you can change that to just an if.
2. You can simplify code blocks by using guard clauses that have the following layout:

   ```
   if a:
       ...
   else:
       raise b
   ```

   To:

   ```
   if not a:
       raise b

   ...
   ```
3. You can use `a in [b, c]` rather than `a == b or a == c`.
4. As commented by [Michel Billaud](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/71438/michel-billaud), "The code will be shorter with an auxiliary variable `id = validated_data['user_institution'].id`".

Employing the above would get the following which I find to be much easier to read.

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    user = self.context['request'].user
    if user.role == 'super_admin':  # ref PR 25.1
        return Transaction.objects.create(**validated_data)

    if user.role not in ['user', 'org_admin', 'site_admin']:  # ref PR 25.4
        raise serializers.ValidationError({'Error': 'You are not assigned a role.'})

    id_ = validated_data['user_institution'].id
    if not check_user_institution_exists(id_):
        raise serializers.ValidationError({'Error': 'This user institution does not exist.'})

    if check_user_belongs_to_institution(id_, None, user.id) <= 0:
        raise serializers.ValidationError({'Error': 'You do not belong to this institution.'})

    if not check_upload_permission(id_):
        raise serializers.ValidationError({'Error': 'You do not have upload permission for this '
                                                    'institution.'})

    return Transaction.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

Comment: The code will be shorter with an auxiliary variable  `id = validated_data['user_institution'].id`

Comment: @MichelBillaud That's right, I'll add that now :)

Comment: also, the last three tests could be delegated to a function call `assert_user_institution_allows_upload(id_,institution_)`  whose role is to raise some exception if user is not allowed.